# Reallocation prints out error

Tags: c

Does anyone know why this reallocation code doesnt work?

```
 typedef struct symbol{  
    char **arg; 
    int alloc_pam; 
    } TSymbolPtr

    TSymbolPtr symb;

    symb.arg = realloc(symb.arg, (70));
```

Here is error which prints out:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./ifj: realloc(): invalid next size:     (SIGABRT)
```

Code example:

hopefully itll be clearer. Even thought it wont let me post it unless I add more details, it is possible that this long code wont be sent at all :(

```
int rParams_n()
{
  int result;
  actToken = getNextToken();
  result = rType();
  i++;
  if(i >= symb.alloc_pam){
    printf("\trealloc \n");
    symb.arg = (char **)realloc(symb.arg, (symb.alloc_pam) * 2); //error
    symb.alloc_pam *= 2; 
  }
  symb.arg[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)* ((strlen(actToken.data)) + 1));
  strcpy(symb.arg[i],actToken.data);
  actToken = getNextToken();
...  
}
/* 
 * <params> -> <type> "ID" <params_n> 
 * <params> -> "EPSILON"
*/
int rParams()
{
  count=0;
  if(symb.arg == NULL)
    symb.arg = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (symb.alloc_pam));
  int result;
  // <params> -> "EPSILON" - params je prazdne, cekam ")"
  if (actToken.typ == PZAVORKA) return ERR_CODE_SUCC; // vracim se do rFunc
  // else jedu podle <params> -> <type> "ID" <params_n>

  result = rType();
  if (result != ERR_CODE_SUCC) return result;
  symb.arg[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ((strlen(actToken.data)) + 1));
  strcpy(symb.arg[i], actToken.data);
  count++;
  i++;
  actToken = getNextToken();
    symb.arg[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ((strlen(actToken.data)) + 1));
  strcpy(symb.arg[i],actToken.data);
  actToken = getNextToken();
  // rule rParams_n
  result = rParams_n();
..
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `symb.arg` allocated?

Comment: symb.arg = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (5));

Comment: arg needs to hold an array of pointers.  Unless your system is 16-bit, the number 70 is not a multiple of your pointer size.

Comment: That's usually caused by heap corruption, in my experience. Try running the program with Valgrind or Dr. Memory

Comment: Please show a real, complete code example.

Comment: Perhaps, it has to write beyond the allocated area.

Comment: `realloc(symb.arg, (symb.alloc_pam) * 2);` you probably want that to be `realloc(symb.arg, sizeof(char *) * (symb.alloc_pam) * 2);`

Comment: this type of declaration `rParams_n(void)` should be used instead of `rParams_n()`, when you want no parameters. Empty parameter braces is an obsolescent feature at this point.

Comment: You never initialize `symb.arg` anywhere (and you don't say whether it has static storage duration or not)

Comment: Thanks, @kaylum .. it's working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `realloc()` is a size in *bytes*, not *array entries*.  It should always be a multiple of the data size.

```
symb.arg = (char **)realloc(symb.arg, (symb.alloc_pam) * 2); //error
```

`symb.arg` is a pointer to pointer, which means that the number of bytes must be a multiple of `sizeof(char*)`.  Using the literal `2` only works on a 16-bit platform.  You should instead use `sizeof` to get the number of bytes.

```
symb.arg = (char **)realloc(symb.arg, sizeof(char*) * (symb.alloc_pam) * 2);
```

Comment: I think the `2` is needed to increase the size of the buffer (the buffer already has `sym.alloc_pam` entries). That is, should be `symb.alloc_pam * 2 * sizeof(char*)`

Comment: @kaylum Note: `sizeof(char*) * symb.alloc_pam * 2` does not overflow as readily as `symb.alloc_pam * 2 * sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: @chux Oh, ok. Can you please explain why? Something to do with the intermediate values? I can start a new question if need be :-)

Comment: @kaylum `sizeof(char*)` is type `size_t`. `symb.alloc_pam` and `2` are both `int`. Should the ranges differ, their product is of the larger type.  Assuming either approach is mathematically representable as a `size_t` (the argument type for `realloc()`), With `symb.alloc_pam * 2`, code has another limitation: `symb.alloc_pam` is limited to `INT_MAX/2`.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say since we don't know the current size of **arg nor what (70) is supposed to mean.

Your **arg is being used to allocate a dynamic array of pointers, yes?

If you're trying to allocate 70 char * here you need to use sizeof(char *) * 70:

```
symb.arg = (char **) realloc(symb.arg, (sizeof(char *) * (70)));
```

this is, of course - assuming that symb.arg is already allocated - if you're using the above method to do so it's unlikely but impossible to say at this point.

We can then use the dynamically allocated char * to allocate buffers, is that what you're trying to do?

```
symb.arg[0] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (lengthofstring + 1));
```

For example. Hope this helps but like I said it's hard to say with only sporadic snippets of your program being posted.

ETA - sorry, my mistake - I see your calls to malloc() and they look fine, realloc is the same only difference is you pass the pointer to be resized as the first argument - the second argument to realloc() is essentially the same as your first and only argument to malloc().

Answer (score 0):

Allocating insufficient space as the 2nd argument to `realloc()` needs to be scaled by the width of the objects.

Rather than guess the type, let the compiler do that work.

```
// symb.arg = (char **)realloc(symb.arg, (symb.alloc_pam) * 2); //error

// Notice no type used in this line-of-code
symb.arg = realloc(symb.arg, sizeof *symb.arg * (symb.alloc_pam) * 2);
```